# Mysql does'nt distinguish between characters "c" and "ç" in UNIQUE index

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, on-duplicate-key

I have simple table with 2 fields:

```
first: `id` INTEGER primary key auto-incremented
second: `symbols` VARCHAR unique key 3-length utf8_general_ci.
```

Lets say there is just one row already (comma separates fields):

```
1, c
```

now I want to add some more:

```
2, ç
```

but mysql says that this is duplicate entry because of "c" already exists... but "c" isn't "ç", field is in utf8_general_ci, same with utf32_general_ci.

How to fix this?

Comment: I think you'll have to use the `utf8_bin` collation as shown out in the other question.

Comment: You are right, thanks.